# Cron Scheduling Stopped Suddenly

Tags: php, magento, cron

Magento Enterprise Ver : 1.13

My cron scheduler has stopped suddenly.

When i checked cron_scheduler table i am not getting any entry there after 16th Jan.
I have tried a lot but unable to find any lead regarding what would have stopped it.

Its not scheduling jobs after running the cron.php manually also.

Hence please suggest if any one knows where to look or any way to track down the problem.

Refrence : cron.sh is having 777 permission

Comment: By paid you mean magento team does provide help for enterprise version ?

Comment: is the cron job running correctly under the same user account the web server is running on?

Comment: No i mean is cron service paid? you might want to check for subscription plans..

Comment: No its not a paid service. I am trying to set the cron for default magento services like log cleaning etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `$ crontab -e` on your server and check your cron configuration.

You can add `MAILTO=your.email@example.com` at the beginning of the file to send an email for every cron that is fired.

You'll probably get the error message there.